# What should be preferred for rate limiting? AWS WAF or nginx as proxy server or both?

Tags: nginx

We have our backend on jetty server and frontend on Apache server. 
Both these are on AWS EC2 instance. Now we want to implement API rate limiting for our application. Then what would be the good approach to follow? AWS WAF or nginx as proxy server between frontend and backend server or both?